# How to read date (Timestamp) from MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

Am trying to read date field from MongoDB in below format

```
Formate: YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS

2017-01-23-10.46.07.812000 - DB2
2017-01-23T16:46:07.812Z   - Stored in MongoDB (While viewing from GUI tool)
Mon Jan 23 22:16:07 IST 2017 - Result/Reading from MongoDB

// Formatter for the input date
final DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
final ZonedDateTime dateFiledParsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateFiled.toString(), inputFormat);
final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
System.out.println(outputFormat3.format(publicationDateParsed));

Result: 2017-01-23 22:16:07.000000
```

In the result 2017-01-23 22:16:07.**000**000, instead of 000 it should be the 812 (Original value: 2017-01-23-10.46.07.812000)

Note: Using MongoDB Java driver 3.4.

Thank you in advance!

Bharathi

Comment: If it's actually a BSON Date ( which means it appears as `ISODate` when viewed in the `mongo` shell ) then anything that resolves to `java.util.Date` is the expected input format for queries. If you are sending any other format then it will not be a match. Also note to use UTC values instead of local times unless you understand the conversion process.

Comment: What is `dateFiled` or the string output of `dateFiled.toString()`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - dateFiled is "Date dateFiled = "some date"

Comment: `Date` and `Timestamp` are two very different types in MongoDB, according to [the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/working-with-dates#the-mongodb-date-and-timestamp-types). I suggest you edit the Question to clarify which one you intend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date accordingly. For example, assuming you inserted the date in MongoDB using [the proper ISODate type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date):

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("597813a12dbe1d773beb11d2"),
  "date": ISODate("2017-01-23T16:46:07.812Z")
}
```

This code prints the correct date:

```
Document doc = collection.find().first();
Date date = doc.getDate("date");
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
formattedDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(formattedDate.format(date));
```

Output is:

```
2017-01-23 16:46:07.812
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Its woks as expected

Comment: how can i do this when working with dozer mapper

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked the next code, when passing a `date` to MongoDb:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

When retrieving it:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

this 2 methods will match mongo's date format (util.Date in java)

```
public static String convertToString(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone));
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public static Date convertToDate(String strDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone));
    Date parsedDate = null;
    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return parsedDate;

}
```