# How to retrieve the timestamp from the ObjectID field in mongodb document in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, jongo

I want to query all the documents in a collection to get the timestamp of each document from the ObjectID, as there is no separate createdAt fieldin the documents. How do i structure the query for the same in java?

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp also https://gist.github.com/tebemis/0e55aa0089e928f362d9,

Comment: Your question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296105/how-to-read-date-timestamp-from-mongodb-using-java

Comment: @ManuelRapino The question is different the user already has a date field in her document.

Comment: @dkb I've already gone through the document. But I'm not understanding how to pass it to a query. And the other link works for Js.

Comment: Hi @EmmaVaze, could you clarify what are you intending to do ? Your question implies that you would like to retrieve timestamp value, but your comment suggest that you would like to query using the timestamp. Perhaps a rough example of query would be useful.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I'm trying to retrieve the timestamp from the object id for the documents in a collection in java.